# Displaying a popup after form submit with no action

Tags: php, jquery

So I have a form button on my site that once successfully submitted, will display a popup with additional information (information that is not relevant for this question).

The form contains minimal information that is collected automatically and is in the form of just a single button that a user clicks.  After clicking said button, a popup confirmation is displayed using jQuery. After confirming/canceling the submission within this popup confirmation, the user's page is either refreshed and the button gone (if confirmed) or the box is simply exited with no submission (if canceled).  Again, I want a new popup box to appear only after it's confirmed and after the page has refreshed.

Relevant code that I have thus far:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="delivery-confirm-frm">
      <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<?php echo $_order->getIncrementId(); ?>" />
      <input type="button" value="Confirm" class="delivery-confirm" />
</form>
<script>
var $jj = jQuery.noConflict();
$jj(document).ready(function () {
    $jj('.delivery-confirm').on('click', function () {
        var _this = $jj(this);
        $jj.confirm({
            title: 'Confirm!',
            content: 'Are you sure? Once confirmed, you cannot dispute this transaction.',
            buttons: {
                confirm: function () {
                    _this.closest('form').submit();

                },
                cancel: function () {

                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Would this require AJAX to accomplish?

Comment: If it's a minimal amount of information, why not just use ajax and display a message in the `success` event handler?

Comment: Well that's why I asked the question, because I haven't yet had any experience with AJAX. Was curious if it's possible with just PHP/JS or if I'll need to extend my scope a bit and learn some AJAX.